# How to customize node page view?

Tags: drupal-7

There is a list of cars for rent (list of nodes of material type "car rental"). Each car has a page of details. On the page there is a table of the cost depending on the duration of the lease (here is page screenshot):

[image: Cost table]

As I see it, I need to add fields for the type of material "car rental":

- Day
- Week
- Weekend
- 7-21 days
- > 21 days
- Deposit

And then, somehow, render this fields to a table.

How to best implement it in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

How to do it best might vary depending on who you talk to. But I would probably use a node--car_rental.tpl.php solution. And code the table my self in html. This restricts the page to be dynamic with more fields, but it is easy to implement. But if you want more dynamic solution without needing to coding files, I would use the [Display Suit](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module
 and some CSS.